# Problem in virtual inheritance

Tags: c++

```
class base { 
protected: 
    base() {} 
}; 

class der1 :  virtual private base { 

public: 
    der1() {} 
}; 

class der2 : public der1
{
public:
    der2() {}

};

int main() {
    der2 d;
}
```

It gives compile time error: 'base::base' : cannot access inaccessible member declared in class 'base'

But base class constructor is define publically it compiles.

Pls anyone can give explaination?

Comment: what is _virtual inheritance_ ?

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator: Virtual inheritance is usually used to solve the diamond problem in inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Because `base` is a virtual base class, it must be initialized by the most derived class in the hierarchy of an object being instantiated. `base`'s contructor may be protected and accessible to classes derived from it, but that doesn't help as `base` is a private base class of `der1` so even classes derived from `der1` don't have access to the `base` parts of "`*this`".

You need to relax the access restrictions on the base `base` class to at least `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

The base class constructor is declared `protected`, but that is not the problem. The main problem will be the private inheritance in `der1`. This way, `der2` cannot access the constructor of `base` which it needs in order to construct itself.

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `virtual private base`
with `virtual protected base` and `der2` will be able to access to the constructor of `base`